# FirebaseFirestore.Timestamp vs firebase.firestore.Timestamp on React Native client and Admin Node server

Tags: typescript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I'm trying to solve an issue that seems like it should be an easy fix, but I can't find anything in the documentation about it, and there doesn't seem to be any questions regarding it.

I'm building an app with React Native, where we create various documents relating to the app, and send these to a Firebase function running an express server that connects to Firestore with the Admin SDK for node@10. My issue is trying to find some sensible way to represent dates without having to convert everything back and forth every time, since there are quite a few date fields in my documents/subdocuments. I initialize the react native firebase connection with `import * as firebase from firebase`and `firebase.initializeApp(...config)` here. The Timestamp object for this library has type `firebase.firestore.Timestamp`. Meanwhile, on my server, I initialize with `import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'` and  `admin.initializeApp(credential, ...config)`. Here, the type of Timestamp is FirebaseFirestore.Timestamp, and comes from the google-api library, instead of the firestore library. When I then send an object with this type from the server to the client, or the other way around, typescript compilation fails because the two types are incompatible.

My most recent attempt at doing this was to use the `Date` object, but when I send this to Firestore, it automatically converts it to a `FirebaseFirestore.Timestamp` object, which leads me back to my original problem of not wanting to manually convert every object before I typecheck it (on each end of the REST API).

Any tips or hints on how I can fix this? I know I don't have a reproducible example here, but I don't really see the need for it, since it's more of a type issue than actual programming.

Thanks for any help!

(I also can't use `@firebase/testing`'s `initializeTestApp()` because of this, because FirebaseFirestore.Firestore and firebase.firestore.Firestore are two different types, which I don't know if in the same category of error as this one.)

Comment: "*Any tips or hints on how I can fix this?*" - I don't think anything is broken.  The timestamps are working as expected.  And the APIs for client and server libraries are different, which is OK.  What really is the problem here?  Are you unwlling to use the native timestamp types on both client and server, as they are designed?

Comment: I'm really happy if there are no issues, but the two types don't overlap (as far as I can tell). So when I create a Timestamp in the client, it breaks the server because the type doesn't fit and vice versa. I should be able to create a timestamp on the client, right? @DougStevenson

Comment: I think you're going to have to edit the question to illustrate with code and specific observations.  What exactly is "broken"?  I've written lots of code to read and write timestamps from both client and server using web and node.  It always works.  I don't expect the client and server APIs to overlap.  They are different, but they both deal with timestamps just fine.  You're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: It's the first time I'm building with firestore, so I'm sure there's something wrong. I'll work on an example and get back with it.

Comment: could you share a snippet from your code for have a better context of this issue?

Comment: @DougStevenson My error was that I was using the same interface shared between the two (thus forcing the backend to use the web-version of the Timestamp, which did not work). Now I've recreated the interfaces on each end of the API, and it looks like it's working.

Comment: @HarifVelarde I would, but it seems the issue resolve itself. As you can see in my above comment, it was related to my type declarations, and nothing to do with firebase itself.

Comment: @XBullet123 nice, could you share as an answer how you fix this issue? On this way you could help more people with the same scenario

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this was as simple as I had hoped (feared). I had simply defined my interfaces in one singular place, and expected the types to cooperate, but instead, I needed to declare two separate interfaces for the different types of `Timestamp`:

Clientside:

`TimestampedValue.ts`

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
export interface TimestampedValue {
    value: string;
    time: firebase.firestore.Timestamp;
}
```

Serverside:
`Timestampedvalue.ts`

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
export interface TimestampedValue {
    value: string;
    time: admin.firestore.Timestamp;
}
```

This helped me at least!